# Attribute in FLutterflow is unaccessible

Tags: flutterflow

[image]

I have this structure where the start button creates a new document with few fields filled first, but when i want to update the same document, im not able to set it as its in red. the column is a backend query to call 'daily_programs' single document. Below is the data i want to update and the actions im trying

[image]
[image]

As you see the time_end and success is in red. im unsure how and when should i update the document. Even the action on timer ends which is inside the timer, these attributes are not updatable. Im still very new to flutterflow would appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you need to pass not the actual field you want to update, but a reference to the record, and then specify what exactly you want to change. From the FlutterFlow docs:
https://docs.flutterflow.io/actions/actions/backend-database/firestore#3.-update-document

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).